# Liquid indicator locations in a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, damage

Does anybody know how many liquid indicators are there in a MacBook Pro and where are they located exactly?

I am in particular interested in the [2018 15" MBP model](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i9-2.9-15-mid-2018-true-tone-display-touch-bar-vega-16-vega-20-specs.html).

I could not find this information on ifixit.com .

Answer (score 0):

The number of Liquid Submersion Indicators and their placement vary from model to model, so you cannot in general say where they are in any MacBook Pro.

There's nothing you as a user can do to "reset" the indicator in case this was the reason for your question. Even if you could somehow "reset" the indicator, liquid damage to a computer is usually very self-evident. You will see buildup of verdigris on the electronics (a green/blue substance occurring on copper parts).

Comment: I am aware of that. I just want to find a plan of the internals with the locations of the liquid indicators.

Comment: Might even vary within a model.  I accidentally ruined a keyboard on a Mac laptop.  When I tried to replace it with a keyboard from a SAME model number laptop, the connector was a different shape and had a different number of pins.